# Android: ListView - toggling the visibility of a image on choosing an item

Tags: android

I've got a listview with a text and an image in it. What I want to achieve is when I select a list item, I need to set only the associated image in the row to visible. When I choose another list, the previously associated image should be invisible and the current one to visible (similar to ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE).

Please can anyone give me a headstart on the same. Do let me know if anyone wants more explanation.

**EDIT:** My Custom Adapter class

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private Context context;
    private List<String> list = null;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflator;
    private Typeface typeFaceRegular;

    //constructor
    public CustomListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<String> list) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, list);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;

        if (view == null) {
            layoutInflator = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.launcher_custom_list, parent, false);
        }

        String info = list.get(position);

        if (info != null) {
            typeFaceRegular = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "Roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf");
            TextView txtvwLauncherListText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtvwLauncherListText);
            txtvwLauncherListText.setText(info);
            txtvwLauncherListText.setTypeface(typeFaceRegular);
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: you'd have to create a custom adapter then in the adapter's `getView()` you can toggle the picture visibility. If you want an example I can post one

Comment: @john: Thanks for your reply.
To give you a background, I've already implemented a custom adapter for the same. Check my updated question, I've added my adapter class. Could you please guide me further on the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an item click listener for the listview, and in that do

```
{
adapter.SetSelectedPos(position);
adapter.notifyDatasetChanged);
}

adapter.SetSelectedPos(int pos) // pos comes from the above listener
{
 _pos = pos; //_pos define in adapter class
}


// in getView do
if(_pos == position)
{
//Show image
}
else
{
// hide image (this hide is important and required)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Since this is a listView, would this handle the scenario wherein only the image on which the item was selected, would be shown. Rest all would not be shown?

Comment: yes definitely else case should hide all, thats i wrote its really imp